# How to set Jupyter Notebook path to linux file

Tags: python, jupyter

[image]

I'm running ubuntu 20.04 on chromeos. I want to open up an html file in a cell which is currently in my downloads folder. I've tried multiple variations of the file path in:

```
from IPython.display import IFrame
IFrame(src='/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Downloads/MySite.html', width=900, height=600)
```

How do I set an absolute path to the file?

Comment: you can execute system commands from a jupyter notebook cell by prepending an exclamation mark, e.g. `!ls /mnt`. You can then use `ls -l` to explore folder structure and permissions

Comment: I've changed the screenshot after following your idea. Still not getting it to work.

Comment: ok, I think I got it. Try adding `file://` in front of the path

Comment: I tried : IFrame(src='file:///mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Downloads/message_zdm.html', width=900, height=600) - not working - I'm not getting an error but the output is blank

Comment: apparently localhost is considered a remote site. [For security reasons](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don't_work), remote websites cannot access local files. What worked for me is reading file content and then using HTML widget to render it